# Can I try out XMir/Mir on a 13.10 startup disk?

Tags: 13.10, mir, startup-disk

I'd like to try out XMir on 13.10, but currently don't have a spare machine to install it on (and I understand it doesn't play nice with VirtualBox).

I have a startup disk created from the 13.10 daily images, but so far as I can tell this is running a regular X session and not XMir.  So, how would I go about trying out XMir here?  The typical add-the-PPA method?  Or can I expect that the startup disk images will include XMir by default in the near future?

Comment: If you're willing to take a look at the Xubuntu version by installing on a USB stick, check out http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2165540 and https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/xubuntu-devel/2013-August/009205.html.

Comment: How about ubuntkylin version? I don't know how to find out which version currently use MIR.

Comment: Today I downloaded a daily image (`saucy-desktop-amd64.iso`).  Getting XMir up and running was as simple as adding `universe` to the software sources, and then following the instructions at http://unity.ubuntu.com/mir/installing_prebuilt_on_pc.html followed by a restart.  I'm pleased to report that on my system at least (ThinkPad T420 with Intel graphics) it seems to work very nicely and without issue, apart from the anticipated one of not yet supporting switching between displays.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, its just a package install and a restart of lightdm:-

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mir/Installing

This is only for the Gallium open driver though, if you want to try nVidia binary driver that a different ball game.

Comment: It's instructions like those which are in that link that are (one of) the reasons I love Ubuntu.